# onClick function call using scriptlet code

Tags: jsp, servlets

i want to add a button when i click it the date should be displayed but the button doesn't work .

my servlet:

```
package test.servlets; 

  import java.io.*;
  import javax.servlet.*;


      public class FunctionalTestServlet extends HttpServlet
        {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws    

        ServletException, IOException {



     response.setContentType("text/html");
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  
      String text = request.getParameter("montext");
      String fileName = request.getParameter("testclass");

      out.println("<b><font color='blue'>The text is :</font></b>" 
      + "<b>"+ text +"</b>" + "<br>");

      out.println("<b><font color='blue'>The File name is :</font></b>" 
              + "<b>"+ fileName+"</b>" + "<br>");


      out.println("<% public void executeTest() {" +

 " java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date();out.println(d.toString()); } %>");
 **out.println("<input type='submit' value='Execute Test'onclick='executeTest()'>");**

    }


}
```

jsp page :

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   

"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
   </head>
      <body>

    <html:file properties="tonFichier" name="tonForm"/>

    <form action="FunctionalTestServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="get">
    <p>
  Type some text (if you like):<br>
  <input type="text" name="montext" size="30">
   </p>
    <p>
    Please specify a Test , or a set of tests:<br>
   <input type="file" name="testclass" size="40" >
    </p>
   <div>
  <input type="submit" value="Execute Test">

     </div>
   </form>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Any idea please 
Cheers

Comment: What doesn't work, what do you see when you click it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly wrong:

```
out.println("<% public void executeTest() {" +
```

You cannot generate scriptlet code in servlet. Scriptlet code belongs to JSP. Any text returned from JSP (sent to `out`) is sent directly to the client. Thus the HTML delivered to the browser will contain scriptlet code - which should have been evaluated on the server-side!

Scriptlets can only appear in JSP.

To make it even funnier, you are trying to attach Java `executeTest()` method as a JavaScript `onclick` handler - will never work:

```
out.println("<input type='submit' value='Execute Test'onclick='executeTest()'>")
```

In fact your code is broken is so many ways that it requires complete rethink/rewrite. Start from understanding how, when and where servlets, JSP and JavaScript works.

I kind of get your idea and guess what, it doesn't require neither JSP nor servlets. Just write `onlick` handler in JavaScript and modify the DOM somehow to print current date.

Comment: what @tomasz said is completely true, in order to achieve what you want you may use javascript like the following :

out.println("<script type='text/javascript'> function f(){ var d=new Date(); document.write(d); } </script> ");
  out.println("<body><input type='submit' value='Execute Test' onclick='f()'></body>");

Comment: Thank you much for the explaination :)))